# How to attach layout(made by java) to fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, fragment

I want to make `fragment` example without using any `xml` file

I tried to make `layout` with java only.
After that, I want to attach it to `fragment`.

But the `class` which `override fragment` have to return `xml` file by using inflate.
(Is it right?)

Also, since `fragment` is not a `Activity`, I can't use `setContentView` on it.

How can I solve this problem?

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

public FragmentA() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
    tv.setText("Hello World1");
    linear.addView(tv);


    return inflater.inflate((XmlPullParser) linear, null);
}
}
```

I want to make fragment example without using any xml file

Comment: Change to `return linear;`. That's it.

Comment: `linear` is View instance not need to use inflate method , just return `linear` instance from `onCreateView `

Comment: I think too far ahead... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call the `inflate method`, you can just return the `linear` variable.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LinearLayout linear = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linear.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
    tv.setText("Hello World1");
    linear.addView(tv);


    return linear;
}
```

The `inflate` method is used to load a `View` defined in an XML file into memory. As far as you have created a new instance of `LinearLayout` using context, there is no need to inflate anything.